# iPad App submission error

Tags: ipad, itunes

The binary you uploaded was invalid. When supporting iPad only, the iPhone OS Deployment Target must be 3.2.

**What is this??!?!?!?!**

This happens everytime I try to upload my binary file to iTunes Connect

Comment: Well, is your deployment target set to 3.2 or not?

Comment: -1 for too many exclamation marks

Comment: We understand all questions posted to stackoverflow are important.  Extra emphasis is not required.  It actually just causes some people to skip over the question.  We know you are frustrated.  If you ask the question we will answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that you need to make sure the deployment target is 3.2 in the target -- it's easy to get confused by different levels you can set this at in Xcode.